# If an entire function $f$ satisfying $f(i) = f(-i) = f(1) = f(-1) = f(i + 1) = 0$ show that $f\equiv 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm stuck on the following question.

> Let $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be an entire function satisfying the following conditions :
>
> - $f(i) = f(-i) = f(1) = f(-1) = f(i + 1) = 0$ and
> - $\lim\limits_{z \to \infty} \frac{f(z)}{z^{5}} = 0$.
>
> Show that $f$ is identically zero.

I don't know how to use the conditions at all. There is the theorem saying that if there exists a $z_{0}$ in a connected open set $U$ such that $f^{(n)} = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $f(z) = 0$ in $U$. There is Liouville's theorem. And some others but I can't make them work in this case.

I hope the explanation will help me getting better at using the theorems.

Thank you a lot in advance.

Comment: Yes. The question is in french but I believe the translation of "identiquement nulle" is "identically zero". Oh they give a hint : you can express $f^{(k)}(0)$ with a well chosen integral for $k = 0, 1, 2, \dots$.

Comment: Ah, well... I don't know, this is a question of an old exam but perhaps they made a mistake.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience and answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider , $$g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{(z^4-1)(z-1-i)}$$Then , $g$ is entire.

Also , $|g(z)|\to 0$ as $z\to \infty$. So $g$ is bounded and hence by Louville's theorem $g$ is constant , say $C$. Then $f(z)=C(z^4-1)(z-1-i)$.

Now , $$\lim_{z\to \infty}\frac{f(z)}{z^5}=0\implies C\lim_{z\to \infty}\frac{(z^4-1)(z-1-i)}{z^5}=0\implies C=0.$$Hence , $f\equiv 0$.

Comment: But isn't $\lim\limits_{z \to \infty} \frac{f(z)}{z^{5}}$ equals to 1 instead of 0 in the case you present ?